# Python: Using Selenium in Google Colab to automatically input data into Google Drive

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Thanks in advance for your effort of looking into this issue.

I have been trying to code in Python to create an automation script that could automatically input data into the Google Forms on Google Colab, the form contains **2 pages**.

1st Page
Nothing else, just some description of the form and **a "Next" button**.

2nd Page
1 Multiple Choices Question and **2 buttons,  "Next" and "Submit"**

My code should click on the first "Next" and tell me how many buttons are there in the 2nd page, and the answer is obvious: 2 with the index of 0 and 1, but it seems like it was still stucked at the first page rather than going to the second page.

I have attached my code so that we can figure out together.

Thanks!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
import time
from time import sleep

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("--headless")
option.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
option.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

chromedriver_location = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_location,options=option)
driver.get("some_form_link")



radiobuttons = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("appsMaterialWizToggleRadiogroupOffRadio")
checkboxes = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("quantumWizTogglePapercheckboxInnerBox")
linearscales = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("appsMaterialWizToggleRadiogroupRadioButtonContainer")
submitbutton = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("appsMaterialWizButtonPaperbuttonContent")


print("all class found successfully")

#to direct the form to the next page
next_links = driver.find_elements_by_link_text("Next")

print("first page test passed successfully")
sleep(3)


print(len(submitbutton))
print(len(radiobuttons))
#the output of mine are as below:
#all class found successfully
#first page test passed successfully
#1
#0
```

Comment: `driver.get("some_form_link")` - Can you share the links ?

Comment: Absolutely, there you go. It was a "Back" and "Submit" Button, mistakes in the original question.

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSc3zh-qETI2WDHgxXCGZ0JtMxdTYdWZ0zwNc2Y3NjythtBl0g/viewform?fbzx=-599222426261136088

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that we cannot edit the first page `description` text box. So I have written a script that would click on `Next` button and select a `B` `option` in the second page and finally click on `Submit` button :

**Sample code :**

```
!pip install selenium
!apt-get update 
!apt install chromium-chromedriver

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver =webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSc3zh-qETI2WDHgxXCGZ0JtMxdTYdWZ0zwNc2Y3NjythtBl0g/viewform?fbzx=-599222426261136088")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Next']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label[for='i8']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Submit']"))).click()
print("Operation successful !")
```

Comment: This is a useful solution that works thank you so much, may you explain why my:
next_links = driver.find_elements_by_link_text("Next")
doesn't work?

Comment: You are using `find_elements` which will return a list of web elements, we do not want list for clicking on a next button, we just want a single web element so if you change that to `find_element`, probably it should work